# Skill Flow Builder Lambda Function reset the DynamoDB

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

Apologies for the title of this question. It's hard to put it any other way. I have built an Alexa skill using their new dev tools (Skill Flow Builder). This tool has a feature that deploys the skill and creates the Lambda function you need to run it. This Lambda function uses DynamoDB to store information about variables, and the scene names that represent your current position in the skill as you progress through it.

I have edited the skill, and have been testing it thoroughly, but I have now removed all of the old scenes and replaced them with new ones that have new names.

Now, when I deploy and try to run the skill, it is throwing an error because it is trying to find the name of a scene that no longer exists. It is doing this because it wants to resume the skill at that point. The old scene name is stored in the DB.

Here is the error message thrown by the Lambda function:

```
{"errorMessage":"Cannot find the scene not interesting.","errorType":"Error","stackTrace":["StoryAccessor.getSceneByID (/var/task/node_modules/@alexa-games/sfb-f/dist/storyEntities/StoryAccessor.js:28:19)","ACEDriver.processScene (/var/task/node_modules/@alexa-games/sfb-f/dist/driver.js:435:47)","ACEDriver.resumeStory (/var/task/node_modules/@alexa-games/sfb-f/dist/driver.js:188:41)","<anonymous>","process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)"]}
```

It is the scene that was called "not interesting" that it can no longer find.

The question is, how can I reset the skill so it is not using the DB to resume the skill at the last point?

Answer (score 0):

The answer, of course, is to spin up a new DynamoDB Table when you have significant changes to your Skill: in my case, a complete change in the Scene names.

In the Skill Flow Builder `abcConfig.json` file edit the `dynamo-db-session-table-name` string which is in the `default` object with all the other settings for your skill. Give it a new name and then re-deploy. It will build a new Table.